# anaconda installed package not importable

Tags: python, gtk

I have tried to install 'gtk' for python on Ubuntu (14.04). It seems to be installed OK. However I'm unable to import it.

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)

$ python -c 'import gtk'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named gtk

$ which python
```

It seems to be installed OK...

```
$ conda list | grep -i gtk
conda list |grep -i gtk
gtk                       3.16.6                        2    ostrokach
```

I've only got one `conda` environment.  `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONHOME` are unset.

```
$ conda info -a
Current conda install:

               platform : linux-64
          conda version : 4.3.24
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.24
    conda-build version : 1.19.0
         python version : 2.7.13.final.0
       requests version : 2.18.3
       root environment : /home/manohar/anaconda2  (writable)
    default environment : /home/manohar/anaconda2
       envs directories : /home/manohar/anaconda2/envs
                          /home/manohar/.conda/envs
          package cache : /home/manohar/anaconda2/pkgs
                          /home/manohar/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/brian-team/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/brian-team/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : /home/manohar/.condarc
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.24 requests/2.18.3 CPython/2.7.13 Linux/3.13.0-123-generic debian/jessie/sid glibc/2.19    
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
# conda environments:
#
root                  *  /home/manohar/anaconda2

sys.version: 2.7.13 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (64-bit)| (defaul...
sys.prefix: /home/manohar/anaconda2
sys.executable: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/python
conda location: /home/manohar/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda
conda-build: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-build
conda-convert: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-convert
conda-develop: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-develop
conda-env: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-env
conda-index: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-index
conda-inspect: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-inspect
conda-metapackage: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-metapackage
conda-pipbuild: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-pipbuild
conda-server: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-server
conda-sign: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-sign
conda-skeleton: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin/conda-skeleton
user site dirs: 

CIO_TEST: <not set>
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV: <not set>
CONDA_ENVS_PATH: <not set>
LD_LIBRARY_PATH: <not set>
PATH: /home/manohar/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin
PYTHONHOME: <not set>
PYTHONPATH: <not set>

License directories:
    /home/manohar/.continuum
    /home/manohar/anaconda2/licenses
License files (license*.txt):
Package/feature end dates:
```

Any ideas as to what to check next? There are a plethora of `gtk`-related files inside `~/anancoda2`:

```
~/anaconda2/share/gtk-3.0  (containing gtkbuilder.rng)
~/anaconda2/include/gtk-3.0  (many header files and subfolders)
~/anaconda2/bin/
    gtk3-demo-application
    gtk3-demo
    gtk3-icon-browser
    gtk3-widget-factory
    gtk-encode-symbolic-svg
    gtk-launch
    gtk-query-immodules-3.0
    gtk-update-icon-cache

~/anaconda2/lib/
    gtk-2.0
    gtk-3.0
    libgtk-3.la
    libgtk-3.so
    libgtk-3.so.0
    libgtk-3.so.1600.6
```

Comment: Does `from gi.repository import Gtk` work? `import gtk` gives you the outdated gtk2.

Comment: Thank you @Rawing. I get `no module named gi.repository` with that. Also: this is in order to get some legacy code to work!